# for loop getting data in batch

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
M=2
for i in range(20):
    for item in range(M):
       print (data[item])
    item=item+1
    M=M+10
```

basically I want to get data in batches , I mean I want to loop 20 times and each time I want to get M data

the above is not working and **item** is setto 0 
any idea how to accomplish that ?

here is a better example

```
outlist = []
for m in range(20):
   for i in range(M):
     out=i
    outlist.append(out)
 print(outlist)
```

the output will be:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

and I want the output to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, .........]
```

Comment: What's your expected output for this? What is `data`? Show a sample of the contents and what you expect

Comment: I want to increment item every time I exit the second loop

Comment: `outlist.append(m)` for 2nd example will do the job

Comment: nope, it will print 00 , 11 , 22....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the typical way to work with lists in batches or chunks:

```
batch_size = 20
data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...]

for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
    print(data[i:i+batch_size])
```

If you have an iterator and not a list, you will need to use `itertools.islice` to accomplish a similar thing:

```
from itertools import islice

batch_size = 20
data = (i*2 for i in range(100))

while True:
    chunk = list(islice(data, 0, batch_size))
    if not chunk:
        break
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: not sure that what I am looking for, let's say I have a container of balls for example (1000) but I can not ask for the whole 1000 one time, I want to take 100 each time . this means I have to contact the container 10 times and each time I will get 100

Comment: @Moo define "container"

Comment: container= a list of 1000 item

Comment: Right so you would just take `batch_size = 100`, and `data` is your container of lots of items, as in the 1st example.